# Best practice for using codacy in my jenkins pipeline

Tags: codacy

Currently, I have subscribed to codacy pro.

And I want to use codacy in my Jenkins pipeline, and I found [codacy-analysis-cli](https://github.com/codacy/codacy-analysis-cli).

I tried to do a test on my local using this command:

```
codacy-analysis-cli analyze --directory /home/codacy/backend-service --project-token <myprojectoken> --allow-network --verbose --upload
```

But when I checked app.codacy.com, there were no recent results.

Can you help me please? what is the best practice for using codacy in my jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

That command seems about right, on this cases, is better to reach out to Codacy support specifying what is the repository that you are trying send results to. So you can get specific help for your repository.

That said, make sure that:

- The project-token is set for the correct repository
- The settings have the `Tun analysis through build server` enabled

[image: repo_settings]

If you still have problems, better to reach out to support.